# Kusto query that does case-insensitive filter on tag names (keys) instead of values

Tags: azure, filter, kql, azure-resource-graph

In our Azure environment we have resources that contain tags that haven't been consistently named with regard to the use of upper and lowercase. Say we have a tag `Projectteam`. In our environment we would have all kinds of variants of that tag name:

- Projectteam
- ProjectTeam
- projectTeam
- ProJeCteAm

You get it, the use of upper and lowercase spelling could be all over the place.

What I want is a Kusto (KQL) query that filters on that `Projectteam` tag in a case-insensitive way. I found lots of examples on filtering on a tag's **value** in a case-insensitive way, but here I want to do that on the tag name itself. If I use this query:

```
Resources
| where tags.Projectteam == 'TeamX'
```

It will only return resources that have a tag whose name matches `Projectteam` exactly. I won't get any resources that use different case spelling, like `projectTeam`.

I could of course apply some filter on the `tags` property value, like using the case-insensitive `contains` operator:

```
Resources
| where tags contains 'projectteam'
```

But that might also return unwanted results, where `projectteam` is used as a value instead of a tag name (key). It also feels like there should be a better way.

Does anybody know a better way to filter on a tag name in a case-insensitive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Resources
| where tags has "ProjectTeam" and tags has "TeamX"
| where tags[tostring(bag_keys(tags)[array_index_of(parse_json(toupper(tostring(bag_keys(tags)))), toupper("ProjectTeam"))])] == "TeamX"
```

Demo on ADX:

```
let Resources = datatable(ID:long, tags:dynamic)
[
    1 ,dynamic({"dummy1": 1, "dummy2": 2, "Projectteam": "TeamX"})
   ,2 ,dynamic({"ProjectTeam": "TeamX"})
   ,3 ,dynamic({"projectTeam": "TeamX"})
   ,4 ,dynamic({"ProJeCtteAm": "TeamX"})
   ,5 ,dynamic({"ProjectTeam": "TeamY"})
   ,6 ,dynamic({"OtherTeam": "TeamX"})   
   ,7 ,dynamic({"OtherTeam": "TeamX", "ProjectTeam": "TeamY"})
];
Resources
| where tags has "ProjectTeam" and tags has "TeamX"
| where tags[tostring(bag_keys(tags)[array_index_of(parse_json(toupper(tostring(bag_keys(tags)))), toupper("ProjectTeam"))])] == "TeamX"
```

| ID | tags |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"dummy1":1,"dummy2":2,"Projectteam":"TeamX"} |
| 2 | {"ProjectTeam":"TeamX"} |
| 3 | {"projectTeam":"TeamX"} |
| 4 | {"ProJeCtteAm":"TeamX"} |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WSTU%20EMBCG7yT8hwmnNuECfiUYDkYvetGYPWgIIV0YWVZoSVuiRP3vjguusK5ue2hm%20sz7Tqat0cI9GtXpHA3EUAhLe1kju76KaiVLH6woTVT0UjRVzl0ncR2gFYA/5tibV3RN0wdeBIEPQxBSEFJwp9Uac2tRNJTxFnQ%20eB98o%20GHU42RXOwlj6Zk%20x95vKN5g5fkfrGHPDng/rglT6fkrV2h3vUmakDPDqA/I/ltlZ67zvYtXOcdXqgcN/OHlTDzShCymFwN6vOixCpjdSVLthRl9oy9YV9pngitRZ9VssDXTD2xVmiD2dooyazq2hY1%206OSFv2HkZm1w3nKU4jj704%20AZc0fGdYAgAA)

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work. But this does seem a bit convoluted :-)

Comment: Indeed. It is not a trivial use case since JSON is case-sensitive. You are talking about a use-case where each document has a different variation of the key, but actually a JSON like the following, is valid: `{"Key":1, "KEY":2, "kEy":3}`.

Comment: In addition, Azure Resource Graph currently supports only a very limited subset of KQL.

Comment: Yes, I understand why JSON-wise is perfectly legal. Our Azure resources grew like this organically. We now have policies in place to (hopefully) prevent this tag inconsistency for newly created resources. The existing ones we'll fix at a later time. What's funny is that the Azure Portal doesn't allow you to add multiple tags, that only differ case-wise.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [`bag_keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction) to extract the tag keys.

```
Resources
| extend keys = bag_keys(tags)
| where keys contains "ProJeCteAm"
```

It can be even simpler using [`bag_has_key`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bagkeysfunction):

```
Resource
| where bag_has_key(tags, "ProJeCteAm")
```

Comment: If I understand correctly your solution only returns resources that contain the tag in some form. But it doesn't allow me to filter on their value. How would I then filter the result, so that only `Projectteam` tag (which again, might use all sorts of casings) values are returned that match `TeamX`?

Comment: @LeonZandman True it will only allow you to find all resources. You can use the other answer for finding `TeamX` values. You can use my answer to find all offending resources and fix the tags ;-)